# Не устанавливаются модули

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Я пишу в VS code и хочу установить модуль `discord.py`. Пишу `pip install discord.py`, он загружается, но при запуске кода:

```
PS C:\Users\<личн. инфа>\Desktop\Документы\Программы> & C:/Users/<личн. инфа>/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310-32/python.exe c:/Users/<тоже личн. инфа>/Desktop/Документы/Программы/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\<личн. инфа>\Desktop\Документы\Программы\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
```

Comment: Может, Вы не то виртуальное окружение используете

Comment: Либо несколько python установлено, pip запускается от одной установки, интерпретатор от другой.

Comment: Пробовали IDE перезапускать?

Comment: @S_Smerch покажите весь код проекта

Comment: @Robot у меня два проекта, один просто бот, другой музыкальный бот. Я вообще раньше писал на replit, там не надо было устанавливать модули...  В данном случае эта ошибка в VS code в музыкальном боте.  Весь код скорее всего не влезет, так что: `TT | S_Smerch#2902`